# How to pass configuration parameters to SimpleInjector packaging?

Tags: configuration, settings, inversion-of-control, packaging, simple-injector

So SimpleInjector now has a packaging nuget that you can use to isolate different aspects of root composition.

Say I have a configurable composition root in a library that is reused by multiple projects in an application. For example, in an Azure solution I might have a Web role and a Worker role which share a large set of the same dependencies for the most part, but with slightly different configuration options depending on the consumer. When I compose the root, I can pass in a plain old `RootCompositionSettings` object with properties that tell SimpleInjector how to register dependencies.

However, I am not sure how (or if) I can pass these settings to an `IPackage` instance. Is it possible to pass custom settings to a SimpleInjector package, and if so, how?

I see that the standard practices for registering packages is to invoke either

```
container.RegisterPackages(); // scans all loaded assemblies for IPackage
// or
container.RegisterPackages(IEnumerable<Assembly>) // specific assemblies only
```

...so how can we pass parameters into the packaging instance(s)? Is there some way to do it via the container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick here is to pass the information on with the container to the package. You can do this by using the container's `Items` dictionary, that is much like ASP.NET's `HttpContext.Items` collection. This can be done as follows:

```cs
using SimpleInjector.Advanced;

container.SetItem(typeof(RootCompositionSettings), settings);

container.RegisterPackages();
```

Now inside your packages, you can do the following:

var settings = 
        (RootCompositionSettings)container.GetItem(typeof(RootCompositionSettings));

Please note that:

- `SetItem` and `GetItem` are extension methods that are located in the `SimpleInjector.Advanced` namespace. Those methods allow you to access the (internal) `Items` dictionary.
- You can pass in any key you like. Passing in `typeof(RootCompositionSettings)` is just convenient in this case, but not required.

If you need to call the settings in more places, it might be useful to create a more specific extension method that allows you to access the setting instance, but that's up to you.

Another option is to not use the `IPackage` interface and the SimpleInjector.Packaging library at all. In most cases it doesn't really add anything and you could simply define a public static method in the assembly that does the same as a package does. For instance:

```cs
public static class BusinessLayerBootstrapper
{
    public static void Bootstrap(Container container, ScopedLifestyle scopedLifestyle,
        RootCompositionSettings settings)
    {
        // Here the same logic as what you would write in your package.
    }
}
```

Most applications are not that dynamic that you need to load assemblies dynamically and the startup project usually has a hard reference to all the other assemblies. In that case it is perfectly sane to simply call a static method.

And even if you have the requirement of dynamically loading assemblies and allowing them to register their stuff in the container, it's quite trivial to build your own `IPackage` abstraction instead:\

```cs
// Your own IPackage interface
public interface IPackage
{
    void RegisterServices(Container container, RootCompositionSettings settings);
}

// Your own extension method
public static void RegisterPackages(this Container container, 
    RootCompositionSettings settings)
{
    var packages =
        from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        from type in assembly.GetExportedTypes()
        where typeof(IPackage).IsAssignableFrom(type)
        where !type.IsAbstract
        select (IPackage)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    packages.ToList().ForEach(p => p.RegisterServices(container, settings));
}
```

In fact, except for some extra validations and filtering out dynamic assemblies, the SimpleInjector.Packaging project is not much more than this.